# Laravel 3 vs Laravel 4 : Crypter whats is equivelent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have in laravel 3:

```
$user_id = Crypter::decrypt(str_replace(' ', '+', Input::get('session')));

Crypter::encrypt(Auth::user()->id));
```

How can I replace those with laravel 4? any idea?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean laravel 4 and 5?

Comment: Lafrvel 4.2 to be exact

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4 (and 5) the name of the Facade is now `Crypt`. So now it would be:

```
$user_id = Crypt::decrypt(str_replace(' ', '+', Input::get('session')));

Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id));
```